# Error Validation input Multiple forms blade foreach in Livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a little problem with Live wire in my first approach:
I have created a multiple forms by a foreach of an array

```
array:3 [▼ // resources/views/livewire/multiple-forms.blade.php
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 18
    "name" => "Giovann Innangi"
    "role" => "Moderator"
    "image" => "Test.jpeg"
    "description" => "descr.........."
    "ordering" => 4
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▶]
  2 => array:6 [▶]
]
```

this is my form :

```
   @foreach($members as $index=> $v)
       {{ $index }}
        <form  wire:submit.prevent="save(Object.fromEntries(new FormData($event.target)))" wire:key="{{$index}}" >
            <div wire:key="id-{{$index}}">
                <input
                    wire:model.lazy="members.{{ $index }}.name"
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    class="border-2 bg-gray-500
                    @error('members.{{ $index }}.name') border-red-500 @enderror"
                    value="{{ $v["name"] }}"
                >

                @error('members.{{ $index }}.name')
                <span class="error">
                    errore
                        {{ $message }}
                    </span>
                @enderror
                <button class="bg-blue-500" type="submit">Save {{ $index }}</button>
            </div>
        </form>

   @endforeach
```

The problem is that when the required name field is of 3 caractes if i have clicked on first element form the error appear on all forms

**form1 clicked **
errore The members.0.name field must be at least 6 characters. buttom Save 0

form2
PippoX
errore The members.0.name field must be at least 6 characters. buttom Save 1

form3
Marco Polo
errore The members.0.name field must be at least 6 characters. buttom Save 2

Solutions??? :(

I want know if there is solution to skeep the problem of realtime validation in multiple form.Becaus online i dont ssee a solution of this case.

My Solution is:

> @error('members.'.$index.'.name')

Comment: I need show the error on form clicked but live wire show the error in all 3 forms: -------------------------------------------
                                                                                                                                       
 **form1 clicked **The members.0.name field must be at least 6 characters. buttom Save 1

form2 buttom Save 2

form3 buttom Save 3